# How can I find out why a Django database .save() failed?

Tags: django

My Django database .save() is throwing an exception. Is there a way to find out why?

My main code is:

```js
        for i in data['movies']:
            try:
                id = i['regions'][0]['products'][0]['product_id']
                title = i['regions'][0]['products'][0]['product_title']
                m = Movie.objects.get(preview_id=id)
            except Movie.DoesNotExist:
                try:
                    movie = Movie()
                    movie.preview_id = id
                    movie.title = title
                    movie.details = i['regions'][0]['products'][0]['description']
                    movie.date = i['regions'][0]['products'][0]['upd_date']
                    movie.trailer = i['regions'][0]['products'][0]['clips'][0]['files'][0]['url']                   
                    movie.likes = 0
                    movie.dislikes = 0
                    movie.save() # THIS IS THROWING AN ERROR
                    print id + ": " + title
                    for genre in i['regions'][0]['categories']:
                        try:
                            g = Genre.objects.get(title__exact=genre['name'])
                            movie.genres.add(g)
                        except Genre.DoesNotExist:
                            g = Genre(title=genre['name'])
                            g.save()
                            movie.genres.add(g)
                    for pic in i['regions'][0]['pictures']:
                        if pic['type_name'] == "poster_large":
                            movie.picture = pic['url']
                            movie.save()
                except:
                    print 'error'

        print 'Success'
```

My movies model looks like this:

```js
class Movie(models.Model):
    # Movie Model store all the detail of a movie
    # Each movie is created by a User
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    details = models.TextField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=filename, blank=True, null=True)
    trailer = models.FileField(upload_to=videoname, blank=True, null=True)
    # genres = ManyToMany with Genre Model
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, related_name='genres')
    likes = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dislikes = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    trigahs = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    # Director with People Model
    director = models.ForeignKey(People, blank=True, null=True)
    # Casts = ManyToMany with People Model
    casts = models.ManyToManyField(People, related_name='casts', blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    amazon_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    preview_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def add_likes(self):
        self.likes = self.likes + 1
        self.save()

    def add_dislikes(self):
        self.dislikes = self.dislikes + 1
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        super(Movie, self).save()
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = '%s' % (
                slugify(self.title)
            )
        super(Movie, self).save()
```

And the super function is defined as follows:

```js
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        """
        Saves the current instance. Override this in a subclass if you want to
        control the saving process.

        The 'force_insert' and 'force_update' parameters can be used to insist
        that the "save" must be an SQL insert or update (or equivalent for
        non-SQL backends), respectively. Normally, they should not be set.
        """
        # Ensure that a model instance without a PK hasn't been assigned to
        # a ForeignKey or OneToOneField on this model. If the field is
        # nullable, allowing the save() would result in silent data loss.
        for field in self._meta.concrete_fields:
            if field.is_relation:
                # If the related field isn't cached, then an instance hasn't
                # been assigned and there's no need to worry about this check.
                try:
                    getattr(self, field.get_cache_name())
                except AttributeError:
                    continue
                obj = getattr(self, field.name, None)
                # A pk may have been assigned manually to a model instance not
                # saved to the database (or auto-generated in a case like
                # UUIDField), but we allow the save to proceed and rely on the
                # database to raise an IntegrityError if applicable. If
                # constraints aren't supported by the database, there's the
                # unavoidable risk of data corruption.
                if obj and obj.pk is None:
                    raise ValueError(
                        "save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to "
                        "unsaved related object '%s'." % field.name
                    )

        using = using or router.db_for_write(self.__class__, instance=self)
        if force_insert and (force_update or update_fields):
            raise ValueError("Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving.")

        if update_fields is not None:
            # If update_fields is empty, skip the save. We do also check for
            # no-op saves later on for inheritance cases. This bailout is
            # still needed for skipping signal sending.
            if len(update_fields) == 0:
                return

            update_fields = frozenset(update_fields)
            field_names = set()

            for field in self._meta.fields:
                if not field.primary_key:
                    field_names.add(field.name)

                    if field.name != field.attname:
                        field_names.add(field.attname)

            non_model_fields = update_fields.difference(field_names)

            if non_model_fields:
                raise ValueError("The following fields do not exist in this "
                                 "model or are m2m fields: %s"
                                 % ', '.join(non_model_fields))

        # If saving to the same database, and this model is deferred, then
        # automatically do a "update_fields" save on the loaded fields.
        elif not force_insert and self._deferred and using == self._state.db:
            field_names = set()
            for field in self._meta.concrete_fields:
                if not field.primary_key and not hasattr(field, 'through'):
                    field_names.add(field.attname)
            deferred_fields = [
                f.attname for f in self._meta.fields
                if (f.attname not in self.__dict__ and
                    isinstance(self.__class__.__dict__[f.attname], DeferredAttribute))
            ]

            loaded_fields = field_names.difference(deferred_fields)
            if loaded_fields:
                update_fields = frozenset(loaded_fields)

        self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
                       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
    save.alters_data = True
```

This is all code I am taking over so much of it is a mystery to me. Apologies if this question is not properly framed. But could really do with a pointer as to how to track down the reason for failure.

Comment: Share your traceback.

Comment: You would know if you didn't hide the error. Never, ever, use a bare `except:` when you're not properly handling the exception.

Comment: This is code I have taken over and am still coming up to speed with Django. How would you recommend handling exceptions?

Comment: Your comment prompted me to add the 'Exception as e' bit to the except which did of course reveal the error! Thanks.

Comment: print the exception. Or simpler, remove the second `try` block to see it. Also read about python exceptions and django database exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try:
    line 1
    line 2
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

This will reveal the error. This is only for debugging. You should properly handle the exceptions.

Comment: I tried try:
            {model}.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)